# iOS app validation fails because it can't find Info.plist

Tags: xcode, cordova

I've recently recreated an app (a PhoneGap one) and it builds fine, but when it comes to validation it fails because it can't find the Info.plist. I had to rename the project which is probably why. There are two references as far as I've found using Find, in the project files, both set to "isys Collect/Info.plist", pointing to a directory called "isys Collect".

Does anyone know if there are other references, or if the file needs to be called something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not that it wasn't finding it, but there was another validation error. I guess it doesn't hit the code that says it's found the plist until it's successfully validated all the items within it. Ugh.